# angular 7 call a service method on a route

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

I have the following routes in an angular 7 app.

```
app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login' }
];

auth.service.ts:
func logout() {
   this.httpClient.get(config.logoutURL);
   window.location.href='/';
}
```

Now when a user types an non-existent url in the address bar, I want to logout the user (using a function defined in the `auth.service.ts`) and then redirect the user to the root url.

Is it possible to do this functioncall+redirection in the router itself, instead of writing a dummy component like `PageNotFound` ? I do not want to have an extra component, because all that would do is, iiuc, on ngInit, it would just call the `logout` function. Any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As you'r already redirecting to `LoginComponent` for all unmatched path you can call you method in `LoginComponent` constructor like

```
constructor(authService:AuthService){
authService.logout();
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-qsajin)

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not rely on making changes in the LoginComponent. If the login url is typed by the user, if a session is already active, I do not want the session to be logged out.